# Validaciones en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, validación, update

Tengo el siguiente problema,
Tengo una aplicación web, en la cual lleno un formulario en el que se adjunta una imagen (en sql solo guardo el nombre de la imagen para después abrirla en otro formulario), al momento de actualizar el registro, si no se actualiza la imagen el SP, va y graba NULL en la base de datos...
Como podría validar que si el parámetro de la imagen va vació, me deje le mismo que ya esta en la tabla???

El codigo que tengo es un simple update al tabla

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FormDetalle] SET [archivoadjunto] = @file,[comentarios] = @Comment,[avance]= @iAvance,fec_finreal=@date
        WHERE [id_1] = @id1 AND [id_accion]=@iAccionID;
```

el parámetro de la imagen es @file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más simple es usar `ISNULL`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FormDetalle] 
SET [archivoadjunto] = ISNULL(NULLIF(@file,''),[archivoadjunto]),
    [comentarios] = @Comment,
    [avance]= @iAvance,
    fec_finreal=@date
WHERE [id_1] = @id1 
AND [id_accion]=@iAccionID
;
```

Comment: no me funciono, lo que trato de hacer es que cuando llegue el parametro vacio al sp, que me deje el que tiene actualmente en la tabla o haga update del mismo valor, o que no haga el update a ese campo

Comment: eso es lo que hace este código, si `@file` es `NULL`, deja el valor anterior en `archivoadjunto`. O por "vacío" te refieres a que en vez de `NULL` llega un caracter vacío? (`''`)

Comment: caracter vacio = ' '

Comment: @Richard actualicé entonces mi respuesta. Ahora debería funcionar si es un caracter vacío o `NULL`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poner algo así:

```
if(@file is null)
begin
  UPDATE [dbo].[FormDetalle] SET [comentarios] = @Comment,[avance]= @iAvance,fec_finreal=@date
    WHERE [id_1] = @id1 AND [id_accion]=@iAccionID;
end
else
  begin
    UPDATE [dbo].[FormDetalle] SET [archivoadjunto] = @file,[comentarios] = @Comment,[avance]= @iAvance,fec_finreal=@date
    WHERE [id_1] = @id1 AND [id_accion]=@iAccionID;
  end
```

Verificas si el parámetro @file es nulo entonces no actualizas ese campo, si trae valor entonces si lo actualizas

Comment: buena respuesta pero igual como le decía a @Lamak, en si no era null era un campo vació, gracias!